Couchbase and App Issue of Spring Boot with Kubernetes
I try to implement an example of Spring Boot with Couchbase. After implementing docker process, I passed Kubernetes one.
I have some problems when I run kubectl apply -f k8s command after starting minikube and opening its dashboard.
Couchbase throws this issue shown below
Failed to pull image "couchbase:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

The app named todowithcouchbase throws this issue shown below
Failed to pull image "noyandocker/todowithcouchbase:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

The docker image is available through this link
Here are the codes shown below
1 ) app-config.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: app-config
data:
  COUCHBASE_BUCKET: "todo_list"
  COUCHBASE_HOST: "couchbase"

2 ) couchbase-pv.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: couchbase-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data/couchbase
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: couchbase-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

3 ) couchbase-secret.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: couchbase-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcg== # Base64 of 'Administrator'
  password: MTIzNDU2           # Base64 of '123456'

4 ) couchbase-secret.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: couchbase
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: couchbase
  serviceName: couchbase
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: couchbase
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: couchbase
          image: couchbase:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8091
            - containerPort: 11210
          env:
            - name: COUCHBASE_ADMINISTRATOR_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: couchbase-secret
                  key: username
            - name: COUCHBASE_ADMINISTRATOR_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: couchbase-secret
                  key: password
            - name: COUCHBASE_BUCKET
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: app-config
                  key: COUCHBASE_BUCKET
          volumeMounts:
            - name: couchbase-storage
              mountPath: /opt/couchbase/var
      volumes:
        - name: couchbase-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: couchbase-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: couchbase-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: couchbase
  ports:
    - name: admin-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8091
      targetPort: 8091
    - name: data-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 11210
      targetPort: 11210
  type: NodePort

5 ) todowithcouchbase-deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: todowithcouchbase
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: todowithcouchbase
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: todowithcouchbase
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: todowithcouchbase
          image: noyandocker/todowithcouchbase:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2323
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: app-config
            - secretRef:
                name: couchbase-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: todowithcouchbase-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: todowithcouchbase
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 2323
      targetPort: 2323
  type: NodePort

How can I fix the issue?
Here is the repo link : Link

Do you have any network policies that might prevent egress traffic reaching out from the cluster to the Internet?

@ChrisDoyle I have no network policy

"Failed to pull image" strongly suggests some sort of networking issue between your cluster and Docker Hub.  You'd have the same issue running an absolutely minimum Deployment that just had the image: and nothing else.  This isn't anything related to the code you've written, and you'll probably need help from the system administrator who set up the cluster.

@DavidMaze I pull prometheus and grafana before but they cannot be pulled.
